# Converting .par files to STL

Tags: software, stl

I am using SolidEdge to create 3D models in .par files and right now I have over 30 files and I need to create STL files to print them in 3D printer using GrabCad

Is there a way to convert all those files in one go instead of converting them one by one by exporting them to STL inside SolidEdge

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange 3D Printing! [Is this what you are looking for?](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/question/0D54O00006fsCG7/exporting-multiple-bodies-to-individual-stls) or is this a different problem?

Comment: No, in my case I have 30 part files and 1 assembly file and I need to convert all the part files into their respective STLs in one go

Comment: Perhaps this helps? https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/solidedge/translating-solid-edge-files-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several software options that can help you convert your .par files to STL files in bulk. Some popular options include MeshLab, Netfabb, and 3D-Tool. These software programs allow you to batch convert your files, saving you time and effort. Additionally, GrabCAD also has a feature called the "Batch Print" tool that allows you to select multiple files and convert them to STL at once. You can access this feature by going to File > Batch Print. I hope this helps!